# error [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. using bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

I'm trying to implement a bottomNavigationBar, but I can't finish it, I'm using Get to handle the routes and the state of the application.

I'm new to flutter, but reading the documentation I still don't understand

This is the main widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.black,
        title: Center(
          child: CommonAssetImage(
            asset: 'logo.png',
            color: AppColors.white,
            height: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: BodyTabsScreen(),
      bottomNavigationBar: HomeScreenBottomNavigatorBar()),
);
```

}

then,I have this widget where call other widget.In this widget I using Obs.

```
class HomeScreenBottomNavigatorBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenBottomNavigatorBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 10,
      color: AppColors.white,
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 27),
        color: AppColors.white,
        child: Obx(() {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab(
                  isActive: true,
                  label: 'Buy',
                  icon: Icons.home,
                  onTap: () {}),
              TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab(
                  label: 'My account',
                  // icon: IkramIcons.user,
                  // iconSize: 20,
                  icon: (Icons.home),
                  onTap: () {}),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

```
class TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final IconData icon;
  final Widget image;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool isActive;
  final double iconSize;
  const TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab({
    Key key,
    this.label,
    this.icon,
    this.image,
    this.onTap,
    this.isActive,
    this.iconSize = 20,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _inactiveTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2;
    final _activeTextStyle =
        _inactiveTextStyle.copyWith(color: AppColors.white);
    const _commonDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 200);
    final _availableSpace = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 27 * 2;
    final _inactiveWidth = _availableSpace * .2;
    final _activeWidth = _availableSpace * .35;
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: _commonDuration,
      width: isActive ? _activeWidth : _inactiveWidth,
      height: 35,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: _commonDuration,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: onTap,
              child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
                style: isActive ? _activeTextStyle : _inactiveTextStyle,
                duration: _commonDuration,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (icon != null)
                      Icon(
                        icon,
                        size: iconSize,
                        color: isActive ? AppColors.white : AppColors.black,
                      ),
                    if (image != null) image,
                    if (isActive)
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                        child: Text(label),
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Getx will always throw that error when you use `Obx` or `Getx` widget without inserting an observable variable that widget. So if you are NOT trying to rebuild a widget based on an updated value of a variable that lives inside a class that exends `GetxController`, then don't use a Getx widget.

If you're just trying to use `Getx` for routing, then make sure to change your `MaterialApp` to `GetMaterialApp` and define your routes, like so.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
      getPages: [
       GetPage(name: Page1.id, page: () =>  Page1()), // add: static const id = 'your_page_name'; on each page to avoid using raw strings for routing
       GetPage(name: Page2.id, page: () =>  Page2()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the `onTap` of your bottom navigation bar just use

`Get.to(Page2());`

Answer (score 3):

It happens when you don't use your controller value in your widget. That's why it gives error because there is no sense in using Obx or Getx() widget

```
    MainController controller = Get.find();
return Obx(
    ()
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text("My pretty text")
            ],
          );
        }
);
```

Solution :

```
MainController controller = Get.find();
Obx(
    ()
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(controller.text)
            ],
          );
        }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Obx widget wrapping your Row widget like this:

```
class HomeScreenBottomNavigatorBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreenBottomNavigatorBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 10,
      color: AppColors.white,
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 27),
        color: AppColors.white,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab(
                  isActive: true,
                  label: 'Buy',
                  icon: Icons.home,
                  onTap: () {}),
              TabsScreenBottomNavigationTab(
                  label: 'My account',
                  // icon: IkramIcons.user,
                  // iconSize: 20,
                  icon: (Icons.home),
                  onTap: () {}),
            ],
          );
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Why? Because you are not using any observable (obs/Rx) variable in your widget tree which would trigger a rebuild when the value changes. So GetX is complaining and for good reason.

Answer (score 2):

The controller should be inside Obx other wise its shows this error.

```
  LeaderBoardController controller = Get.put(getIt<LeaderBoardController>());
    
    
     Obx(()=>controller.leadBoardModel != null
              ? Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 180,
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      LeadBoardImage(type: LEADTYPE.NORMAL),
                      LeadBoardImage(type: LEADTYPE.CROWN),
                      LeadBoardImage(type: LEADTYPE.NORMAL)
                    ]),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.w),
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 4; i < controller.leadBoardModel!.data.result.length; i++)
                      LeaderBoardListItem(result:controller.leadBoardModel!.data.result[i])
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
              : LoadingContainer()),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are two required aspects: 1) extending from a GetXController, and 2) The field/method returning a value from the controller, must be computed from a Rx type. In my case, I made a sub-class of a GetXController for a test, and the return value was hard-coded (not based on a Rx value), and the ObX error occurred.